# JQuery: Checkbox with 3 level auto select child or parent

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a table that look like this:

```
<table border="1">

 <tr>
   <td>Parent</td>
   <td>Child</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" level="parent" name="someparent1" value="1">Parent 1</td>
   <td>
     <li style="list-style-type:none;"><input type="checkbox" level="child"  name="somename1" value"1"> Child 1</li>
     <li style="list-style-type:none;"><input type="checkbox" level="child"  name="somename2" value"2"> Child 2</li>
     <li style="list-style-type:none;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" level="subchild" name="somename1" value="3">Sub Child 1</li>
     <li style="list-style-type:none;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" level="subchild" name="somename2" value="3">Sub Child 2</li>
     <li style="list-style-type:none;"><input type="checkbox" level="child"  name="somename3" value"3"> Child 3</li>
   </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" level="parent" name="someparent1" value="1">Parent 2</td>
   <td>
     <li style="list-style-type:none;"><input type="checkbox" level="child"  name="somename1" value"1"> Child 1</li>
     <li style="list-style-type:none;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" level="subchild" name="somename1" value="3">Sub Child 1</li>
     <li style="list-style-type:none;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" level="subchild" name="somename2" value="3">Sub Child 2</li>
     <li style="list-style-type:none;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" level="subchild" name="somename3" value="3">Sub Child 3</li>
     <li style="list-style-type:none;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" level="subchild" name="somename4" value="3">Sub Child 4</li>   
     <li style="list-style-type:none;"><input type="checkbox" level="child"  name="somename2" value"2"> Child 2</li>
     <li style="list-style-type:none;"><input type="checkbox" level="child"  name="somename3" value"3"> Child 3</li>    
   </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" level="parent" name="someparent1" value="1">Parent 3</td>
   <td>
     <li style="list-style-type:none;"><input type="checkbox" level="child"  name="somename1" value"1"> Child 1</li>
     <li style="list-style-type:none;"><input type="checkbox" level="child"  name="somename2" value"2"> Child 2</li>
     <li style="list-style-type:none;"><input type="checkbox" level="child"  name="somename3" value"3"> Child 3</li>
     <li style="list-style-type:none;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Others Reason: <input type="text" level="subchild" size="50" name="other" ></li>      
   </td>
 </tr>   

</table>
```

And jquery code like this:

```
$('input[@type=checkbox][level$="child"]').click(function(event) {
    var checked = $(this).is(':checked');

    if (checked) {
        $('input[@type=checkbox][level$="parent"]').attr('checked', true);
    }
});

$('input[@type=checkbox][level$="subchild"]').click(function(event) {
    var checked = $(this).is(':checked');

    if (checked) {
        $('input[@type=checkbox][level$="child"]').attr('checked', true);        
        $('input[@type=checkbox][level$="parent"]').attr('checked', true);        
    }
});
```

1) How do i check only current row of parent checkbox when child checkbox is clicked?

2) How do i check only current row of parent checkbox + child checkbox when sub child checkbox is clicked?

-Current issue is when you check 1 subchild it will select all the checkbox there.

-Example (Parent 1 row):
If i select either **Sub Child 1** or **Sub Child 2** the code should be auto select **Child 2** AND **Parent 1**

-JSFiddle Here: http://jsfiddle.net/YDgHN/2/

Any help would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Issue One:

```
$('input[@type=checkbox][level="child"]').click(function (event) {
        var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
        if (checked) {
            $(this).closest('td').parent().children('td').first('td').children('input[@type=checkbox][level="parent"]').attr('checked', true);
        }
    });
```

For Issue Two:

```
    $('input[@type=checkbox][level="subchild"]').click(function (event) {
            var checked = $(this).is(':checked');

            if (checked) {
   // Two select Parent element   
         $(this).closest('td').parent().children('td').first('td').children('input[@type=checkbox][level="parent"]').attr('checked', true);

   // Two select Child element. You will have to loop through all the li elements to //find the appropriate child element 

                $(this).parent().prevAll('li').each(function () {
                    var found = $(this).children('input[@type=checkbox]').attr('level') == 'child';
                    if (found) {
                        $(this).children('input[@type=checkbox][level="child"]').attr('checked', true);
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

For Issue #1 , you can try this:

```
$('input[@type=checkbox][level$="child"]').click(function(event) {
    var checked = $(this).is(':checked');

    if (checked) {
        $(this).parent().parent().parent('tr').find('td:first input[@type=checkbox][level$="parent"]').attr('checked', true);
    }
});
```

Here's a better code for fixing issue one

```
$('input[@type=checkbox][level$="child"]').click(function (event) {

    var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
    $(this).parent().parent().parent('tr').find('td:first input[@type=checkbox][level$="parent"]').attr('checked', checked);

});
```

See, when you select the child, parent will also be selected and vice-versa.

Comment: thanks, this work for child and subchild that will select its parent. however it did not work for subchild to select its child. should we put some identifier for child and subchild so that it know which child it should select?

Comment: I have already said that, `For Issue #1 , you can try this`. Looking into other issues...

Comment: is it possible to use nested <ul> <li> for selecting subchild's child?