# JQuery: Checkbox how to uncheck child and subchild when parent is unchecked

Tags: jquery, checkbox

i already done the select part, but how to do the uncheck part. when i uncheck the parent, it will uncheck the child and its subchild, when uncheck its child will uncheck its subchild.

my code are like this:

the table:

```
<table border="1">

 <tr>
   <td>Parent</td>
   <td>Child</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" level="parent" name="someparent1" value="1">Parent 1</td>
   <td>
     <li style="list-style-type:none;"><input type="checkbox" level="child"  name="somename1" value"1"> Child 1</li>
     <li style="list-style-type:none;"><input type="checkbox" level="child"  name="somename2" value"2"> Child 2</li>
     <li style="list-style-type:none;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" level="subchild" name="somename1" value="3">Sub Child 1</li>
     <li style="list-style-type:none;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" level="subchild" name="somename2" value="3">Sub Child 2</li>
     <li style="list-style-type:none;"><input type="checkbox" level="child"  name="somename3" value"3"> Child 3</li>
   </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" level="parent" name="someparent1" value="1">Parent 2</td>
   <td>
     <li style="list-style-type:none;"><input type="checkbox" level="child"  name="somename1" value"1"> Child 1</li>
     <li style="list-style-type:none;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" level="subchild" name="somename1" value="3">Sub Child 1</li>
     <li style="list-style-type:none;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" level="subchild" name="somename2" value="3">Sub Child 2</li>
     <li style="list-style-type:none;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" level="subchild" name="somename3" value="3">Sub Child 3</li>
     <li style="list-style-type:none;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" level="subchild" name="somename4" value="3">Sub Child 4</li>   
     <li style="list-style-type:none;"><input type="checkbox" level="child"  name="somename2" value"2"> Child 2</li>
     <li style="list-style-type:none;"><input type="checkbox" level="child"  name="somename3" value"3"> Child 3</li>    
   </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" level="parent" name="someparent1" value="1">Parent 3</td>
   <td>
     <li style="list-style-type:none;"><input type="checkbox" level="child"  name="somename1" value"1"> Child 1</li>
     <li style="list-style-type:none;"><input type="checkbox" level="child"  name="somename2" value"2"> Child 2</li>
     <li style="list-style-type:none;"><input type="checkbox" level="child"  name="somename3" value"3"> Child 3</li>
     <li style="list-style-type:none;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Others Reason: <input type="text" level="subchild" size="50" name="other" ></li>      
   </td>
 </tr>   

</table>
```

the jquery:

```
//for child checkbox clicked to select parent
$('input[@type=checkbox][level="child"]').click(function (event) {
        var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
        if (checked) {
            $(this).closest('td').parent().children('td').first('td').children('input[@type=checkbox][level="parent"]').attr('checked', true);
        }   

});

//for subchild checkbox clicked to select child + parent
$('input[@type=checkbox][level="subchild"]').click(function (event) {
            var checked = $(this).is(':checked');

            if (checked) {
// Two select Parent element   
$(this).closest('td').parent().children('td').first('td').children('input[@type=checkbox][level="parent"]').attr('checked', true);

// Two select Child element. You will have to loop through all the li elements to //find the appropriate child element 

                $(this).parent().prevAll('li').each(function () {
                    var found = $(this).children('input[@type=checkbox]').attr('level') == 'child';
                    if (found) {
                        $(this).children('input[@type=checkbox][level="child"]').attr('checked', true);
                        return false;
                    }//end if
                });
            }//end if
});



//for subchild text changed to select child + parent
$('input[@type=text][level="subchild"]').keyup(function(event) {
            var keyvalx = $(this).val();

            //if the value of the text area is not empty
            if (keyvalx != '') {
// Two select Parent element   
$(this).closest('td').parent().children('td').first('td').children('input[@type=checkbox][level="parent"]').attr('checked', true);

// Two select Child element. You will have to loop through all the li elements to //find the appropriate child element 

                $(this).parent().prevAll('li').each(function () {
                    var found = $(this).children('input[@type=checkbox]').attr('level') == 'child';
                    if (found) {
                        $(this).children('input[@type=checkbox][level="child"]').attr('checked', true);
                        return false;
                    }//end if
                });
            } //end if
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YDgHN/3/

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Unless I missed something `level="child"` isn't valid HTML.

Comment: Why not make the "sub child" elements actual descendent elements of the `<li>` containing the "child" element by having a nested `<ul>`? It would make the DOM traversal much, much simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After modified i think this version is perfect: http://jsfiddle.net/YDgHN/21/
not forget credit to other that helped me here:

1) [JQuery: uncheck subchild checkbox inside ul li](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16673917/jquery-uncheck-subchild-checkbox-inside-ul-li/)

2) [JQuery: Checkbox with 3 level auto select child or parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000677/jquery-checkbox-with-3-level-auto-select-child-or-parent)

```
<table border="1">

 <tr>
   <td>Parent</td>
   <td>Child</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td><input type="checkbox" data-level="parent" name="someparent1" value="1" />Parent 1</td>
   <td>
     <ul>  
         <li style="list-style-type:none;"><input type="checkbox" data-level="child"  name="somename1" value="1" /> Child 1</li>
         <li style="list-style-type:none;"><input type="checkbox" data-level="child"  name="somename2" value="2" /> Child 2 <br />
                <ul>
                    <li style="list-style-type:none;"><input type="checkbox" data-level="subchild" name="somename1" value="3" />Sub Child 1</li>
                    <li style="list-style-type:none;"><input type="checkbox" data-level="subchild" name="somename2" value="3" />Sub Child 2</li>
                </ul>
         </li>
         <li style="list-style-type:none;"><input type="checkbox" data-level="child"  name="somename3" value="3" /> Child 3</li>
     </ul>      
   </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td><input type="checkbox" data-level="parent" name="someparent1" value="1" />Parent 2</td>
   <td>
     <ul>
         <li style="list-style-type:none;"><input type="checkbox" data-level="child"  name="somename1" value= "1" /> Child 1<br /> 
                <ul>
                    <li style="list-style-type:none;"><input type="checkbox" data-level="subchild" name="somename1" value="3" />Sub Child 1</li>
                    <li style="list-style-type:none;"><input type="checkbox" data-level="subchild" name="somename2" value="3" />Sub Child 2</li>
                    <li style="list-style-type:none;"><input type="checkbox" data-level="subchild" name="somename3" value="3" />Sub Child 3</li>
                    <li style="list-style-type:none;"><input type="checkbox" data-level="subchild" name="somename4" value="3" />Sub Child 4</li>    
                </ul>
         </li>
         <li style="list-style-type:none;"><input type="checkbox" data-level="child"  name="somename2" value="2" /> Child 2</li>
         <li style="list-style-type:none;"><input type="checkbox" data-level="child"  name="somename3" value="3" /> Child 3</li>
     </ul>   
   </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td><input type="checkbox" data-level="parent" name="someparent1" value="1" />Parent 3</td>
   <td>
   <ul>
       <li style="list-style-type:none;"><input type="checkbox" data-level="child"  name="somename1" value="1" /> Child 1</li>
       <li style="list-style-type:none;"><input type="checkbox" data-level="child"  name="somename2" value="2" /> Child 2</li>
       <li style="list-style-type:none;"><input type="checkbox" data-level="child"  name="somename3" value="3" /> Child 3<br />
                <ul>
                    <li style="list-style-type:none;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Others Reason: <input type="text" data-level="subchild" size="50" name="other" /></li>
                </ul>
     </li>
   </ul>     
   </td>
 </tr>   

</table>
```

JScode:

```
// ########################### for click child to check parent ###########################
$('input[type=checkbox][data-level="child"]').click(function (event) {
        var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
        if (checked) { //when child checked
            $(this).closest('td').parent().children('td').first('td').children('input[type=checkbox][data-level="parent"]').prop('checked', true); 
        } else { //when child un-checked
            //for click uncheck child to uncheck subchild
            $(this).parent().find('input[type=checkbox][data-level="subchild"]').prop('checked', false);
            //for clear text field  on current table row
            $(this).parent().find('input[type=text][data-level="subchild"]').val('');

            //to count checked child
            var countcheckedchild =  $(this).closest('ul').find('input[type=checkbox][data-level="child"]:checked').length;
            //if checked child == 0 then we uncheck the parent
            if (countcheckedchild == 0)
            {                            
                $(this).closest('td').parent().children('td').first('td').children('input[type=checkbox][data-level="parent"]').prop('checked', false); 
            }
        }
});




//###########################  for click parent to uncheck child+subchild+clear textfield ########################### 
$('input[data-level=parent]').click(function() {
//for uncheck all checkbox on current table row    
$(this).parent().next().find(':checkbox').prop('checked', false); 
//for clear text field  on current table row
$(this).parent().next().find('input[type=text][data-level="subchild"]').val('');
});

//########################### for click subchild to select child+parent ###########################
$('input[type=checkbox][data-level="subchild"]').click(function (event) {
        var checked = $(this).is(':checked');

        if (checked) { //when subchild checked
            // to check parent 
            $(this).closest('td').parent().children('td').first('td').children('input[type=checkbox][data-level="parent"]').prop('checked', true); 
            //to check child
            $(this).parents('li:last').children('input[type=checkbox][data-level="child"]').prop('checked', true); 
        } else { //when subchild unchecked

            //count how many checked subchild left
            var countcheckedsubchild =  $(this).closest('ul').find('input[type=checkbox][data-level="subchild"]:checked').length;
            //if checked child == 0 then we uncheck the child
            if (countcheckedsubchild == 0)
            {
                $(this).parents('li:last').children('input[type=checkbox][data-level="child"]').prop('checked', false); 

                // to count how many child selected  
                var countcheckedchild2 =  $(this).parents().find('input[type=checkbox][data-level="child"]:checked').length;

                //if checked child == 0 then we uncheck the parent
                if (countcheckedchild2 == 0)
                {                           
                $(this).closest('td').parent().children('td').first('td').children('input[type=checkbox][data-level="parent"]').prop('checked', false); 
                }
            }



        }
});




//###########################  for subchild textfield  ########################### 
$('input[type=text][data-level="subchild"]').keyup(function(event) {
            var keyvalx = $(this).val();

                //if the value of the text area is not empty
            if (keyvalx != '') {
                // to check parent 
                $(this).closest('td').parent().children('td').first('td').children('input[type=checkbox][data-level="parent"]').prop('checked', true); 
                //to check child
                $(this).parents('li:last').children('input[type=checkbox][data-level="child"]').prop('checked', true);                     
            } else {
                $(this).parents('li:last').children('input[type=checkbox][data-level="child"]').prop('checked', false); 

                // to count how many child selected  
                var countcheckedchild3 =  $(this).parents().find('input[type=checkbox][data-level="child"]:checked').length;

                //if checked child == 0 then we uncheck the parent
                if (countcheckedchild3 == 0)
                {                           
                $(this).closest('td').parent().children('td').first('td').children('input[type=checkbox][data-level="parent"]').prop('checked', false); 
                }
            }
});
```

hope it can help any one else who need it.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest that you change your `level` attributes to either classes, or HTML5's custom `data-` attributes, as they're currently invalid, and your markup won't validate.

With that said, the following will do the trick:-

```
$('input[level="parent"]').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().next().find(':checkbox').prop('checked', false);                             
});
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YDgHN/5/)

Comment: Thanks, this work, how about uncheck child and will uncheck its subchild ( with out uncheck its parent )

Comment: You'd have to add another click handler. As mentioned above though, it'd be a lot simpler if you restructured your markup, and had a hierarchy of parent, children, and sub-children. It'd also mean you'd be able to add a single click handler to do all of the above.

Comment: i have added something like this: $('input[level=child]').click(function() {                           
$(this).parent().next().find(':checkbox').prop('checked', false);                             
});
however it only uncheck the first subchild, no other subchild that checked.

Answer (score 1):

```
        <script>  

            var checkParent  = function(ref) {
                return $(ref).parent().parent().parent().children().first();

            }

           $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
                if(this.checked){
                    $(this).parent().children().find('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', true);
                }

                else {
                    var a = checkParent(this);
                    while(a.length > 0 && a.prop("tagName") == "INPUT" )
                     {
                        a.attr("checked", false);
                        a = checkParent(a);

                    }

                }
           });

        </script>
```

Just completed this algorithm for a project and thought i'll share it on stack flow

Basically, if you check a parent, all the children are selected and when you uncheck a child, all the parents associated with it will be unnchecked because **a Parent can remain checked only if all the children are checked**

Make sure all the checkboxes are within li and all the li are within ul otherwise this won't work

**sample html**

```
<ul id="a">
        <ul id="b">
            <li id="parentli"><input type="checkbox" id="parent"> Parent
                <ul id="c">
                     <li><input type="checkbox" id="aa">Child 1</li>
                     <li><input type="checkbox" id="ab">Child 2
                        <ul id="d">
                             <li><input type="checkbox" id="aba">Child 2-1</li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                     <li><input type="checkbox" id="ac">Child 3</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>

   </ul>
```